# Linking Rust project to cmake project that links to other cmake projects

Tags: c++, cmake, rust, rust-cargo

I'm using the cmake crate to compile a CMake project which depends and compiles other CMake projects

This is my `build.rs`:

```
extern crate cmake;
use cmake::Config;

fn main() {
    let dst = Config::new("src/cpp")
        .define("COMPILE_TARGET", "DESKTOP_x86_64")
        .define("FLAVOR", "DESKTOP")
        .define("LIBOPENVPN3_NOT_BUILD_EXAMPLES", "TRUE")
        .build();

    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native={}", dst.display());
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=libopenvpn3");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=dylib=stdc++");
}
```

This is how my `src/cpp/CMakeLists.txt` compiles `libopenvpn3`

```
add_library(libopenvpn3 SHARED OpenVpnInstance.cpp)
target_link_libraries(libopenvpn3 crypto ssl lzo lz4 tins)
```

However, when I build with `cargo build`, I get undefined references to objects from all these libraries: `crypto ssl lzo lz4 tins`.

I also tried making `libopenvpn3` `STATIC` so the final `libopenvpn3` will include all of the needed libraries: `crypto, ssl, lzo, lz4, tins`, like this:   `add_library(libopenvpn3 STATIC OpenVpnInstance.cpp)` but I still get the error. I think the other libraries (`crypto, ssl, lzo, lz4, tins`) will only be included in `libopenvpn3` if they are static too. Or not?

Anyways, I think that I should relink with these libraries on `build.rs`, like this:

```
println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=dylib=openvpn");
println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=dylib=crypto");
println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=dylib=lzo");
println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=dylib=lz4");
println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=dylib=tins");
```

but I don't know where they are, because they are generated from `CMakeLists.txt`, and I don't think hardcoding the path to where they are generated is a good idea.

What should I do here?

**UPDATE:**

Examples of errors:

```
  /home/dev/orwell/liborwell_rust/src/libopenvpn3/src/cpp/openvpn3/openvpn3/openvpn/openssl/util/pem.hpp:66: undefined reference to `BIO_new_mem_buf'
  /usr/bin/ld: /home/dev/orwell/liborwell_rust/src/libopenvpn3/src/cpp/openvpn3/openvpn3/openvpn/openssl/util/pem.hpp:73: undefined reference to `PEM_read_bio'
  /usr/bin/ld: /home/dev/orwell/liborwell_rust/src/libopenvpn3/src/cpp/openvpn3/openvpn3/openvpn/openssl/util/pem.hpp:91: undefined reference to `CRYPTO_free'
  /usr/bin/ld: /home/dev/orwell/liborwell_rust/src/libopenvpn3/src/cpp/openvpn3/openvpn3/openvpn/openssl/util/pem.hpp:92: undefined reference to `CRYPTO_free'
  /usr/bin/ld: /home/dev/orwell/liborwell_rust/src/libopenvpn3/src/cpp/openvpn3/openvpn3/openvpn/openssl/util/pem.hpp:93: undefined reference to `CRYPTO_free'
  /usr/bin/ld: /home/dev/orwell/liborwell_rust/src/libopenvpn3/src/cpp/openvpn3/openvpn3/openvpn/openssl/util/pem.hpp:95: undefined reference to `BIO_free'
  /usr/bin/ld: /home/dev/orwell/lab/hyper_vpn/target/debug/deps/liblibopenvpn3-7498dcb6c355a9d6.rlib(OpenVpnInstance.cpp.o): in function `SimplePacketCrafter::replaceSourceAddressIpv4(unsigned char*, unsigned long, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)':
  /home/dev/orwell/liborwell_rust/src/libopenvpn3/src/cpp/SimplePacketCrafter.h:117: undefined reference to `Tins::IP::IP(unsigned char const*, unsigned int)'
  /usr/bin/ld: /home/dev/orwell/liborwell_rust/src/libopenvpn3/src/cpp/SimplePacketCrafter.h:118: undefined reference to `Tins::IPv4Address::IPv4Address(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
  /usr/bin/ld: /home/dev/orwell/liborwell_rust/src/libopenvpn3/src/cpp/SimplePacketCrafter.h:118: undefined reference to `Tins::IP::src_addr(Tins::IPv4Address)'
  /usr/bin/ld: /home/dev/orwell/liborwell_rust/src/libopenvpn3/src/cpp/SimplePacketCrafter.h:119: undefined reference to `Tins::PDU::serialize()'
  /usr/bin/ld: /home/dev/orwell/lab/hyper_vpn/target/debug/deps/liblibopenvpn3-7498dcb6c355a9d6.rlib(OpenVpnInstance.cpp.o): in function `Tins::IP::~IP()':
  /home/dev/orwell/liborwell_rust/src/libopenvpn3/src/cpp/libtins/include/tins/ip.h:63: undefined reference to `vtable for Tins::IP'
  /usr/bin/ld: /home/dev/orwell/liborwell_rust/src/libopenvpn3/src/cpp/libtins/include/tins/ip.h:63: undefined reference to `Tins::PDU::~PDU()'
```

Comment: " I get undefined references to objects from all these libraries" - Please, **show** (add to the question post) these errors **exactly**. In case of many errors it is sufficient to show only the first ones.

Comment: @Tsyvarev just updated, take a look. For example, `Tins::IP::~IP()`, this is compiled and linked by `libopenvpn3` and is on `tins`, linked from `target_link_libraries(libopenvpn3 crypto ssl lzo lz4 tins)`

Comment: @Gatonito I need support on this imports..i have a .so which depends on other .so files like crypto, ssl. Can you please guide me steps to get imported all the dependencies together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the CMakeLists.txt, I was doing:

```
install(TARGETS libopenvpn3 DESTINATION .)
```

but then I did

```
install(TARGETS libopenvpn3 crypto ssl lzo lz4 tins DESTINATION .)
```

so it installs all the libs needed

Then, this `build.rs` works:

```
extern crate cmake;
use cmake::Config;

fn main() {
    let dst = Config::new("src/cpp")
        .define("COMPILE_TARGET", "DESKTOP_x86_64")
        .define("FLAVOR", "DESKTOP")
        .define("LIBOPENVPN3_NOT_BUILD_EXAMPLES", "TRUE")
        .build();

    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native={}", dst.display());
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=dylib=stdc++");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=libopenvpn3");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=crypto");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=lzo");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=lz4");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=tins");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=static=ssl");
}
```

I don't know, however, why I have to link them again in Rust. They should be included in libopenvpn3 since they are static, shouldn't them?

Comment: please share me the CmakeList.txt for the above install targets. before this line how i should call the dependecy libs